# "Forcing" satisfying $\kappa^+$-chain condition

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

**Lemma 15.4 of Jech:** Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal such that $2^{< \kappa} = \kappa$.
Let $S$ be an arbitrary set and let $|C| \leq \kappa$.
Let $P$ be the set of all functions $p$ whose domains are subsets of $S$ of size $< \kappa$ with values in $C$.
Let $p < q$ iff $p \supset q$.
Then $P$ satisfies the $\kappa^+$-chain condition.

**Proof:** Let $W \subset P$ be an antichain.
We construct sequences $A_0 \subset A_1 \subset ... \subset A_{\alpha} \subset ... (\alpha < \kappa)$ of subsets of $S$ and $W_0 \subset ... \subset W_{\alpha} \subset ... (\alpha < \kappa)$ of subsets of $W$.
If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, let $W_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} W_{\beta}$ and $A_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} A_{\beta}$.
Given $A_{\alpha}$ and $W_{\alpha}$, we choose for each $p \in P$ with dom$(p) \subset A_{\alpha}$ some $q \in W$ (if there is one) such that $p = q|_{A_{\alpha}}$.
Then we let $W_{\alpha+1} = W_{\alpha} \cup \{\text{the chosen $q$'s}\}$ and $A_{\alpha+1} = \bigcup \{\text{dom}(q) : q \in W_{\alpha+1}\}$.
Finally, $A = \bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} A_{\alpha}$. (The proof continues)

**My problem:** Who is $A_0$? How do I guarantee that $A_1$ and $W_1$ are not empty?

Comment: Does Jech consider $0$ to be a limit ordinal?

Comment: Supposing it does, how can I prove my second question?

Comment: Why the quotes?

Comment: I'm using the result in Theorem 15.17, actually, and there I have a Forcing, but only after asking I realized that Jech doesn't mention $P$ as being a Forcing in the Lemma itself.

Comment: But ok, he define the partial order, so I think $P$ becomes a Forcing after all. Sorry.

Comment: $A_0=\cup _{b<0}A_b=\emptyset.$ The empty function $p_0=\emptyset$  belongs to $P$ and its domain is $A_0.$ Assuming $W$ has at least $2$ members, no $q\in W$ is $p_0$ (else $W$ would not be an anti-chain because $p_0$ is compatible with all $p\in P$). And  any $q\in W$ satisfies $p_0=q|_{A_0}$ so some $q \in W$ belongs to $W_1$, and its domain is not the empty set so $A_1$ is not empty either.... I think you were concerned as to whether every $A_a$ might end up being empty.

Comment: I misreaded the hypothesis about $P$. It's the set of ALL functions..., so of course $\emptyset \in P$. I was concerned with no $p \in P$ satisfying dom$(p) \subset \emptyset$. I don't know what should I do with the post: delete or leave it here?